# Find all value of a

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

For $a\geq 0$ . It know that inequality $3^x+a^x\ge 6^x+9^x$ Is true with $\forall x\in R$ find all value of a .

I use derivative but not know how must go on

Comment: Is it clear that we must have $a>9$, anyway?

Comment: No. Example a=10 then with x=2 is not true

Comment: I didn't say any $a>9$ would work. I said any $a\le 9$ would not. Pay attention to the logic of the language. "We must have $a>9$" doesn't mean that $a>9$ is sufficient. It means it's necessary. Is that clear?

Comment: With x=1 then $a\ge 12$ but not sufficient

Comment: You appear to have some ideas and partial results on this. You should incorporate those into your question, so people trying to answer know what you already understand, and what you don't.

Comment: I  did some plotting and it seems like there is only one value of a for which this works $a=18$

Comment: I want dertrmined  $a\in $ (14,16) or $a\in $ (16,18]

Comment: It appears that any value less than $18$ will cause the equation to fail for small positive values of $x$, and any value greater than $18$ will cause a failure for small negative values of $x$.

Comment: That's based on looking at this graph: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3D(6%5Ex%2B9%5Ex-3%5Ex)%5E(1%2Fx)

Comment: Ok .i also such that .thank you

Comment: It requires that derivative at $0$ should be $0$ for $a$ to be $18$

Comment: Can you explain detail ? Piyush Divyanakar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=3^x+a^x-6^x-9^x$ we have that $f(0)=0$. If the minimum value of the function occurs at $x\neq0$ then the value of derivative at $f'(0)\neq 0$. Why? $x\rightarrow -\infty$ we have that $f'(x)=0$ and at $x\rightarrow\infty$ we have $f'(x)\rightarrow\infty$. So by intermediate value theorem the value of derivative will be non-zero at $0$ if derivative is $0$ at some point less than or more than $0$. This would imply that $f(x)$ will change signs at $0$.

Therefore $f'(x)=3^x\ln3+a^x\ln a-6^x\ln6-9^x\ln 9$ at $x=0$ becomes $$\ln3+\ln a-\ln 6-\ln9=0 \implies a=18$$

Comment: Ok i understand .thank you very much